# Magento 2 interface locale

Tags: magento2, locale

I was wondering whether the selecting one of the languages in the interface locale dropdown in the admin page should change anything ?

It didn't seem to do anything on my installation (`clone from github running in ubuntu instance on AWS`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because there is no official language translation for Magento 2 yet.
There are only stubs for 6 languages.
For example, for German language:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/444e252d40b3a5d5cca3468a9819743af8ed3513/app/i18n/magento/de_de
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/444e252d40b3a5d5cca3468a9819743af8ed3513/app/code/Magento/Backend/i18n/de_DE.csv
As you can see, any translation is absent.

You can do language package by yourself, see the [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, will look through the documentation again.